# Duplicate keys filtering in Dataweave

Tags: filter, mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I have a requirement to read the 'Pronoun' value from the below XML data.
in this scenario `wd:ID` is the duplicate key and I need to read `<wd:Value>` attribute under `<wd:Integration_Field_Override_Data>` object which has `<wd:ID>` = 'Pronoun'

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wd:Get_Workers_Response xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc" wd:version="v33.0">
   <wd:Response_Data>
      <wd:Worker>
         <wd:Worker_Data>
            <wd:Worker_ID>1129</wd:Worker_ID>
            <wd:User_ID>126</wd:User_ID>
            <wd:Integration_Field_Override_Data>
               <wd:Field_Reference>
                  <wd:ID wd:type="WID">916f7f9977422e610e634</wd:ID>
                  <wd:ID wd:type="Integration_Document_Field_Name" wd:parent_type="Integration_Document_Name" wd:parent_id="INT005 - OVERRIDE SERVICE - WORKER">Position as of Hire</wd:ID>
               </wd:Field_Reference>
               <wd:Value>0086186</wd:Value>
            </wd:Integration_Field_Override_Data>
            <wd:Integration_Field_Override_Data>
               <wd:Field_Reference>
                  <wd:ID wd:type="WID">916f7f969d1b57422e610e734</wd:ID>
                  <wd:ID wd:type="Integration_Document_Field_Name" wd:parent_type="Integration_Document_Name" wd:parent_id="INT005 - OVERRIDE SERVICE - WORKER">Probation Period Outcome</wd:ID>
               </wd:Field_Reference>
            </wd:Integration_Field_Override_Data>
            <wd:Integration_Field_Override_Data>
               <wd:Field_Reference>
                  <wd:ID wd:type="WID">438411e0d12510b6d9a0000</wd:ID>
                  <wd:ID wd:type="Integration_Document_Field_Name" wd:parent_type="Integration_Document_Name" wd:parent_id="INT005 - OVERRIDE SERVICE - WORKER">Pronoun</wd:ID>
               </wd:Field_Reference>
               <wd:Value>He/They</wd:Value>
            </wd:Integration_Field_Override_Data>
         </wd:Worker_Data>
      </wd:Worker>
   </wd:Response_Data>
</wd:Get_Workers_Response>
```

I have added a below filtering logic to retrieve 'Pronoun' value however it may impact if they change the order while generating Pronoun ID.
Can you please help me with better approach to perform this action.

```
var pronounData = (worker.Worker_Data.*wd#Integration_Field_Override_Data filter((item, index) -> item.Field_Reference..*ID[1] == 'Pronoun')) default null
```

And retrieve pronoun value as

```
pronoun: pronounData[0].Value
```

Expected Output --> "He/They"

Comment: The expression you use is incorrect because it doesn't start from the payload. Probably you extracted it from a bigger script, but without context is ambiguous. You should have provided a working scripts to reproduce the issue. I´m not sure if omitting the namespace was intentional.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the condition of the filter to check if the array of IDs contains the desired string.

Example:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/java
ns wd urn:com.workday/bsvc
---
(payload.wd#Get_Workers_Response.wd#Response_Data.wd#Worker.wd#Worker_Data
.*wd#Integration_Field_Override_Data 
    filter((item, index) -> item.Field_Reference..*ID contains 'Pronoun'))[0].wd#Value
```

Note that the `default` clause is redundant since the expression already returns `null` if the desired string is not found.

Comment: Thanks for providing the solution. yes it works perfectly fine.